# SwiftUI sheet does not dismiss

Tags: swiftui, dismiss, environmentobject, modal-view

Using Swift5.2.3, iOS14.4.2, XCode12.4,

Working with the `.sheet` modifier in SwiftUI made me feel excited at first since it seemed like an easy and efficient way to display a modal sheet.

However, inside a real-world application it turns out that `.sheet` is all but ready for integration.

Here are two bugs found:

Bug 1:   The sheet does not close sporadically

Bug 2:   The Picker with DefaultPickerStyle does not work when inside a sheet's SegmentPicker ([See this Stackoverlow-question that I created](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67091259/3826232))

Let's focus now on Bug Nr1 : "sheet does not close":

The cmd `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` is supposed to close a sheet. It works 90% of the cases. But every so often and without giving a hin on its reasons, the modal-sheet does not close.

Here is a code-excerpt:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct MyView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Login")) {
                    Button(action: {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: AppConstants.UserDefaultKeys.justLogoutLoginPressed)
                        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                        
                        // supposedly should work all the time - but it only works 90% of the time.....
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text((Auth.auth().currentUser?.isAnonymous ?? true) ? "Login" : "Logout")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to wrap the closing call inside the main-thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

But it did not help.

Any idea why SwiftUI `.sheets` would not close using the `presentationMode` to dismiss it ??

Here I added the way the sheet is called in the first place. Since taken out of a bigger App, I obviously only show an example here on how the sheet is called:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestKOS005App: App {

    @StateObject var appStateService = AppStateService(appState: .startup)
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(appStateService)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class AppStateService: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var appState: THAppState
    var cancellableSet = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(appState: THAppState) {
        
        self.appState = appState                
    }

    // ...
}

enum THAppState: Equatable {
    
    case startup
    case downloading
    case caching
    case waiting
    case content(tagID: String, name: String)
    case cleanup
}
```

```
struct MainView: View {
        
    @EnvironmentObject var appStateService: AppStateService
    @State var sheetState: THSheetSelection?
    
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(named: "title")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                
                ZStack {
                    switch appStateService.appState {
                    case .caching:
                        Text("caching")
                    case .waiting:
                        Text("waiting")
                    case .content(_, _):
                        VStack {
                            Text("content")
                            Button(action: {
                                        sheetState = .sheetType3
                                    }, label: {
                                        Text("Button")
                                    })
                        }
                    default:
                        Text("no screen")
                    }
                }
                .sheet(item: $sheetState) { state in
                    switch state {
                    case .sheetType1:
                        Text("sheetType1")
                    case .sheetType2:
                        Text("sheetType2")
                    case .sheetType3:
                        MyView()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

```
enum THSheetSelection: Hashable, Identifiable {
        
    case sheetType1
    case sheetType2
    case sheetType3
    
    var id: THSheetSelection { self }
}
```

Comment: I don't see sheet in your code. Please provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide the code for the view from which you are calling `MyView` as a sheet.

Comment: I provided the code you asked for. Since this is a rather complex App I provided a minimal excerpt of the entire App. But this gives you the idea. As you can see the sheet is called inside a `NavigationView` in the MainView by pressing a button.

Answer (score 0):

I think when signing out, you probably have an instance checking whether Firebase Auth has an active user session and changes the view to the login screen when you call `try? Auth.auth().signOut()` and it might prevent the `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` is being called.

You might want to create a state property in **MainView** and a corresponding Binding property in **MyView** and manage the state of signing out with them like follows.

In the MyView; instead of calling **signout()** directly;

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var logoutTapped: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Login")) {
                    Button(action: {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: AppConstants.UserDefaultKeys.justLogoutLoginPressed)
                        // try? Auth.auth().signOut() -> instead of this directly
                        logoutTapped = true // call this
                        // supposedly should work all the time - but it only works 90% of the time.....
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text((Auth.auth().currentUser?.isAnonymous ?? true) ? "Login" : "Logout")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

and in the MainView, when creating sheet, in onDismissal block, set a condition on logoutTapped bool state, and logout there like below;

```
struct MainView: View {
        
    @EnvironmentObject var appStateService: AppStateService
    @State var sheetState: THSheetSelection?
    @State var logoutTapped = false
    
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(named: "title")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                
                ZStack {
                    switch appStateService.appState {
                    case .caching:
                        Text("caching")
                    case .waiting:
                        Text("waiting")
                    case .content(_, _):
                        VStack {
                            Text("content")
                            Button(action: {
                                        sheetState = .sheetType3
                                    }, label: {
                                        Text("Button")
                                    })
                        }
                    default:
                        Text("no screen")
                    }
                }
                .sheet(item: $sheetState) {
                    if logoutTapped { // if this is true call signout
                        Auth.auth().signout()
                    }
                } content: { state in
                    switch state {
                    case .sheetType1:
                        Text("sheetType1")
                    case .sheetType2:
                        Text("sheetType2")
                    case .sheetType3:
                        MyView(logoutTapped: $logoutTapped) // send logoutTapped to MyView
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```